# I need to use switch statment to return a word from the set of words

Tags: javascript

Complete the getLetter(s) function in the editor. It has one parameter: a string, , consisting of lowercase English alphabetic letters (i.e., a through z). It must return A, B, C, or D depending on the following criteria:

If the first character in string  is in the set , then return A.
If the first character in string  is in the set , then return B.
If the first character in string  is in the set , then return C.
If the first character in string  is in the set , then return D.
Hint: You can get the letter at some index  in  using the syntax s[i] or s.charAt(i).

```
function getLetter(s) {
    let letter;
    //letter=s.charAt(0)
    const set1= new Set(['a','e','i','o','u']);
    const set2=new Set(['b','c','d','f','g']);
    const set3=new Set(['h','j','k','l','m']);
    const set4=new Set(['n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z']);
    // Write your code here
    switch(s.charAt(0)){
        
        case 1:
        if(set1.has(s.charAt(0)))
        letter=A;
        break;
        
        case 2:
        if(set2.has(s.charAt(0)))
        letter=B;
        break;
        
        case 3:
        if(set3.has(s.charAt(0)))
        letter=C;
        break;
        
        case 4:
        if(set4.has(s.charAt(0)))
        letter=D;
        break;
    }
    return letter;
}
```

Wanted to know what is wrong in this code, I am getting undefined in the result.

Comment: Why do you need to use the `switch` statement? You can remove the switch and just add the `if` statements to assign to `letter` variable. Also, wrap your capital letters in quotes. For example, `A` => `"A"`, `B` => `"B"`, `C` => `"C"` and `D` => `"D"`

Comment: Remove the `switch` and use normal `if-else` blocks. You are using `switch` on an alphabet but using numbers here: `case 1`

Comment: `s.charAt(0)` will not return any of your cases i.e. `1,2,3,4` and `letter` is undefined at return

Comment: this problem asks for switch statement use

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that task makes a lot of sense. Were you given the sets to work with, or did you just make those up for your solution?

Comment: @PushpendraSahu that seems very strange. Not sure how this can be solved with `switch`

Comment: Also, what code was already there in the problem statement? Did you create the `set`s or was it already there? Maybe they are expecting `switch(s.charAt(0)){ case 'a': case'b': case 'c'... etc }`

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/js10-switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check against the set with a boolean value.

```js
function getLetter(s) {
    let letter;
    const set1 = new Set(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']);
    const set2 = new Set(['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']);
    const set3 = new Set(['h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']);
    const set4 = new Set(['n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']);
    // Write your code here
    switch (true) {
        case set1.has(s[0]):
            letter = 'A';
            break;

        case set2.has(s[0]):
            letter = 'B';
            break;

        case set3.has(s[0]):
            letter = 'C';
            break;

        case set4.has(s[0]):
            letter = 'D';
            break;

    }
    return letter;
}


console.log(getLetter('e'));
console.log(getLetter('b'));
console.log(getLetter('k'));
console.log(getLetter('s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a function to check the string. but in all switch cases, you are trying to check what? `switch(s.charAt(0))` this will be evaluated, s.charAt will never can be a number without casting.
So suggestions make always a default case (which will work always)
and case

```
switch (true) {
case set1.has(s.charAt(0)):
  return 'A'

case set2.has(s.charAt(0)):
  return 'B'

case set3.has(s.charAt(0)):
  return 'C'

case set4.has(s.charAt(0)):
  return 'D'
default:
  return 0
```

}

Comment: How is this different to Nina's answer?

Comment: not using a variable 'letter'(no need), as well use JS option to break from the function immediately with a return. and have a default case in case it has some errors